# how to remove gravity from chipmunk?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Hi I am new in game development and want to develop game related to archery.
I am using concept like angry bird .
But the problem is when i through object using slingshot into the air it comes back to the earth because of gravity .I want the object will not come back to the earth and stay at the point where it will reach after thronging.
Can anybody please help me how i can do that.

please please please

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Chipmunk defaults to zero gravity. You have set it explicitly by calling either cpSpaceSetGravity(space, ...) or space->gravity = ...; So just remove the line wherever you do that.